# with R, how to scan the interval value and print out subdata of other dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, character

Dataset 1:

```
dput(kk) 

structure(list(V1 = c(1.05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, 
1.06, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V2 = c(NA, NA, 105.11, 105.12, 
105.13, 105.14, 105.15, NA, 105.94, 105.99, NA, NA, 106.11, 106.12, 
106.13, 106.14, 106.19, 106.2)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))


show(kk)
       V1     V2
1  1.05     NA
2    NA     NA
3    NA 105.11
4    NA 105.12
5    NA 105.13
6    NA 105.14
7    NA 105.15
8    NA     NA
9    NA 105.94
10   NA 105.99
11 1.06     NA
12   NA     NA
13   NA 106.11
14   NA 106.12
15   NA 106.13
16   NA 106.14
17   NA 106.19
18   NA 106.20
```

Dataset 2:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("1.05 ~ 1.06",  "1.07",
"1.08", "1.09 ~ 1.10"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class =
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
           V1
1 1.05 ~ 1.06
2        1.07
3        1.08
4 1.09 ~ 1.10
```

How can I scan the interval value of V1 in dataset 2 and print out the sub category data of dataset 1 which covers the interval on new dataset like above?

Comment: You should probably be more explicit about expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are after something like this:

```
lapply(df2$V1, function(x) {
  z <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split = " ~ ")))
  b <- which(df1$V1 %in% z)
  if(length(b)==0) return(NULL)
  if(length(b)==1) return(df1[b,])
  if(length(b)==2) return(df1[b[1]:b[2],])
})
#result
[[1]]
     V1     V2
1  1.05     NA
2    NA     NA
3    NA 105.11
4    NA 105.12
5    NA 105.13
6    NA 105.14
7    NA 105.15
8    NA     NA
9    NA 105.94
10   NA 105.99
11 1.06     NA

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL
```

Explanation

with

```
lapply(df2$V1, function(x)...
```

you go through elements of `df2$V1` one by one and apply a function on each.

the function first splits the string at " ~ " then converts to numeric after un listing since `strsplit` returns a list and not a vector

```
z <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split = " ~ ")))
```

Then it determines which elements of `df1$V1` are in `z`

```
b <- which(df1$V1 %in% z)
```

And if `b` has `0` elements it returns `NULL`
if `b` has `1` element it returns just one row for `df1$V1`
if `b` has `2` elements it returns a range or rows from `b[1]` to `b[2]`